# Order Items not shown on transnational email

Tags: transactional-mail, ce-1.9.2.4

For some reason, I've not been successful on showing the Order Items on Oder transnational email. I have used the suggested line of coding below:

```
{{/if}} {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}} {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}} {{/depend}} {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}} {{/depend}}
```

And some variations of it. Rest of the email is working good. Anyone knows what is going on?

Many thanks all!

Comment: You should have just `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`. Without any `if` conditions.

Comment: Adarsh, I have also tried without the conditions as suggested without success. It is may be a matter of formatting or other detail I am forgetting. Any other advice?

Comment: Are you able to confirm your template is getting called!

Comment: yes. it is. other changes are positively appearing... Only Order Items aren't displayed :( ... all other variables I want I was able to add